# Is there any way to chain messages together in Grails' message.properties file?

Tags: grails

In Grails there is a `message.properties` file.  In this file message are defined like this:

```
exampleClass.fieldOne.label=Field One

otherExampleClass.fieldOne.label=Field One
```

I want the ability to use both messages even though they are textually the same.  I would like to define them like this:

```
exampleClass.fieldOne.label=Field One

otherExampleClass.fieldOne.label=${message(code: 'exampleClass.fieldOne.label')}
```

... but that just make a a call to `otherExampleClass.fieldOne.label` return the string `${message(code: 'exampleClass.fieldOne.label')}` instead of the desired string `Field One`.

Comment: why don't you just use fieldOne.label once and not worry about the class?

Comment: Because there are places (like in the scaffolding and templates) where I depend on each field of a class having a message label.

Answer (score 0):

In the message.properties I think that you cannot do it, but maybe with a convention and modifying the templates of the Grails you can achieve it. So my idea is:

Define a convention for your messages (for example, initialize the message with some special char)

```
exempleClass.fieldOne.label=FieldOne
otherExampleClass.fieldOne.label=#exempleClass.fieldOne.label
```

Create a TagLib to handle the message

```
class MyTagLib {
  static namespace = "my"
  def inheritedMessage = { attrs, body -> 
    String message = g.message(attrs)
    if(message.startsWith("#")) {
      //get the other message...
    }
    out << message
  }
}
```

And finally [install templates](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Command%20Line/install-templates.html) and change the `<g:message/>` for `<my:inheritedMessage/>` or whatever you call it.

For step 2, another approach is to override `g.message()`, with the benefit of not need the step 3 and make available for all parts of your app the modification. The con is that it will have to be good documented and disseminated or can cause some confusion in other devs.

**EDIT**

To cover all messages I think the better approach is to customize the messageResource used by Grails. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10623388/override-springmessage-tag-with-database-values) is a question that covers how to do it with Spring, to get the messages from the database, could be a start point. And [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1522568/create-a-new-resource-bundle-in-grails) is a question that shows how to replace the bean in Grails.

Comment: Meh, I could not use a taglib everywhere I can use a message (like in another taglib or a class).  If I wanted to so drastically go around the `message.properties` file I would just create a helper class with static variables as message labels (which I don't want to do).  I would really like to contain the message label changes I desire to the `message.properties` file.

Comment: Fair enough. Maybe replacing the bean messageResource then?